# How to false auto open select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I 'm using select2 plugin to autocomplete that is why when I clicked/focus my input my select list is opening automatically and I don't want to open it automatically it must be open when I typed something how can I do that ?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#srehberText").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 2,
    placeholder: "Bölgeyi yazmaya başla",
    templateResult: addUserPic,
    templateSelection: addUserPic
  });

  function addUserPic(opt) {
    if (!opt.id) {
      return opt.text;
    }
    var optimage = $(opt.element).data('image');
    if (!optimage) {
      return opt.text;
    } else {
      var $opt = $(
        '<span class="userName"><img src="' + optimage + '" class="userPic" /> ' + $(opt.element).text() + '</span>'
      );
      return $opt;
    }
  };

});
```

```css
select{
  width:250px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<select id="srehberText" onchange="location = this.value;">
                            <option value="http://www.google.com" data-image="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/all-country-flag/16/Belgium-Flag-icon.png">Alaçatı</option>
                            <option value="http://www.yahoo.com" data-image="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/all-country-flag/16/Canada-Flag-icon.png">Muğla</option>
                            <option value="http://www.bing.com" data-image="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/all-country-flag/16/Hong-Kong-Flag-icon.png">Bodrum</option>
                            <option value="http://www.yandex.com" data-image="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/all-country-flag/16/Aruba-icon.png">Fethiye</option>
                            <option value="http://www.php.net" data-image="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/all-country-flag/16/Montenegro-Flag-icon.png">Karadeniz</option>
                            <option value="http://www.asp.net" data-image="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/all-country-flag/16/Denmark-Flag-icon.png">Nevşehir</option>
                            <option value="http://www.microsoft.net" data-image="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/all-country-flag/16/Guadeloupe-icon.png" >Kapadokya</option>
                            <option value="http://www.microsoft.net" data-image="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-flags/16/United-States-Flag-1-icon.png">Marmaris</option>
                        </select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Select2 isn't an autocomplete library - it just extends a normal select to have filtering functionality (amongst other things). If you want it to behave this way I'd suggest you use an actual autocomplete plugin instead of Select2

Comment: any example that I can use with thumbnail ?

Comment: I think most of them allow you to specify a template for the entries so you can add whatever HTML you like.